# Overriding equals() for use with Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, equals

I have two methods for looking up the index of a particular element in a linked list. I'm trying to use `contais()` and `indexOf()` to find the index. I am unsure how to override `equals()` to suit my need. One method finds the index based on surname and initials the other just the telephone number. Here are my methods:

```
@Override
public int lookupNumber(String surname, String initials) {
    Entry entry1 = new Entry(surname, initials);
    if (listDirectory.contains(entry1)) {
        int index = listDirectory.indexOf(entry1);
        return index;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
@Override
public int lookupName(int extension) {
    Entry entry1 = new Entry(Integer.toString(extension));
    if (listDirectory.contains(entry1)) {
        int index = listDirectory.indexOf(entry1);
        return index;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the `equals()` and `hashCode()` that eclipse provides:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Entry other = (Entry) obj;
    if (extension == null) {
        if (other.extension != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!extension.equals(other.extension))
        return false;
    if (initals == null) {
        if (other.initals != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!initals.equals(other.initals))
        return false;
    if (surname == null) {
        if (other.surname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

But it won't work for both my methods, as it compares all the variables in the objects not just the ones I need it to compare. What is the correct logic for this?

Help much appreciated, thanks.

Update - here is my full Entry class -

```
public class Entry { 

private String surname;
private String initals;
private String extension;



public Entry(String surname, String initals,String extension) { 
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initals = initals;
    this.extension = extension;
}


  public Entry(String surname,String initals){
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initals = initals;
}


public Entry(String extension) {
    this.extension = extension;
}

public String getInitals(){

    return initals;

}

public String getSurname(){

    return surname;
}

public String getExtension(){

    return extension;
}

public void setExtension(String extension) {
     this.extension = extension;
}

public String toString(){
    return surname  + "\t " + initals + "\t" + extension;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((extension == null) ? 0 : extension.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((initals == null) ? 0 : initals.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Entry other = (Entry) obj;
    if (extension == null) {
        if (other.extension != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!extension.equals(other.extension))
        return false;
    if (initals == null) {
        if (other.initals != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!initals.equals(other.initals))
        return false;
    if (surname == null) {
        if (other.surname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

Update - My problem is in my `lookupNumber()` method I want to find elements by `(initials,surname)` whereas in my `lookupNumber()` I want to find elements by `(extension)`. How would I do this?

Comment: You are not showing us your `class`.

Comment: You probably need custom comparators.

Comment: How do **you** define `equals` for objects of **your** class?  If your definition is different from the code **you** have then change it.  Just remember that `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method is a part of your class definition and not a helper method for any business logic.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Object class contains an equals() method of its own, and the Entry class should be the blueprint for objects of type Entry. Java inheritance is such that all classes inherit from the Object class, which is of little use to many of us. Really all you would need is

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Entry otherEntry)
{
    if(!(this.surname.equals(otherEntry.getSurname()))
        return false;
    else if(!(this.initials.equals(otherEntry.getInitials()))
        return false;
    else if(!(this.extension.equals(otherEntry.getExtension()))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The above code just checks for inequality amongst the instance variables, returning false upon any one not equal.